# Webpack indicate entry name from the CLI

Tags: node.js, webpack

I would like indicate my entry name from the CLI for compile many Sass theme.

My package.json :

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack 
  --config ./app/Resources/build/webpack.dev.js 
  --progress 
  --colors 
   --watch THEME_NAME
```

I recovers THEME_NAME in my **webpack.config.js** :

```
var processArguments = process.argv;
var theme = processArguments[7]; // Return theme name
```

And add it in my **entryApp** :

```
entryApp: {
  app: './app/Resources/private/js/app.js',
  theme: './app/Resources/private/scss/themes/' + theme + '/' + theme + '.scss'
},
```

But i've an error :

> ERROR in Entry module not found

I am absolutely certain that the path is good :(

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: show us the processArguments Array - does theme get passed into webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Any argument to the webpack CLI is interpreted as an entry point ([CLI Usage](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#usage-without-config-file)).

When you call:

```
webpack [options] myTheme
```

it tries to find the module `myTheme`, just as if you had specified it as an entry point in the config.

You'll need to use another approach for this. One possibility is to use environment variables.

```
THEME=myTheme webpack [options]
```

Then you can access it with `process.env.THEME` in your config.

Alternatively you can export a function as the webpack config, which returns the configuration object. The webpack CLI will pass any option specified with the `--env` CLI option to the function. See [Exporting a function to use `--env`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function-to-use-env).

With an arrow function which implicitly returns the configuration object, it would look like this:

```
module.exports = env => ({
  entry: {
    entryApp: {
      app: './app/Resources/private/js/app.js',
      theme: './app/Resources/private/scss/themes/' + env.theme + '/' + env.theme + '.scss'
    },
  }
  // Rest of your config
});
```

And you'd call webpack as follows:

```
webpack --env.theme=myTheme [other options]
```